# Rails plugin to run migrations on startup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a plugin available to have Rails run through a db:migrate on startup?  I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve calling out to the Rake task via the shell; so, no "`system('rake db:migrate')`".

I can readily write my own plugin to do this, but figured it would be better to use/improve an existing migrate-on-init plugin if one exists.

Comment: Why would you want one? Having your migrations run automatically, possibly when you don't want them to run, seems like a bit of a risky business to me. Just integrate running the migrations into your deployment automation (you do ''have'' deployment automation, right?) and everything will be much more reliable.

Comment: With womble's answer in mind- perhaps you should write/use a plugin that detects pending migrations and warns you or emails you. Sometimes migrations require other (manual) operations.

Comment: Rails tracks the schema version, so the system won't re-run the same migration, and I'm likely to deploy this app on customer boxes, and don't want them to have to do extra work to handle database setup and upgrades.

Answer (score 4):

Using `config.after_initialize` works, but there are two problems:

1. it runs after all other initializers, so if those initializers do some databasey stuff they'd be using the old schema
2. it runs in all environments, including Rake tasks and Resque workers. We don't want to automatically migrate every time we run `rake routes`, do we? And we don't want multiple migrations to happen simultaneously.

My solution is to use a `config/initializers` file, so I can decide what order it runs in, and to check for whether we're inside a rake task.

Also, until I'm comfortable with auto-migrate on deploy, I'm only doing this in the `development` and `test` environments.

Finally, I want to print some extra information (migrating to and from version), so instead of a one-liner, I reach into the Migrator, perhaps more intimately than I should.

Oh yeah! Also it should write `schema.rb`. So I'm blatantly stealing code from `db:schema:dump` from inside `active_record/railties/databases.rake`. (Wouldn't it be nice if rake tasks were methods on an object, so we could just call them?)

`config/initializers/automatically_migrate.rb`:

```
# don't do this in production
if (Rails.env.development? or Rails.env.test?) and
    # don't do this in a worker or task
    !defined?(Rake)  # SEE BELOW FOR POSSIBLE FIX

  migrations_paths = ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations_paths
  migrator = ActiveRecord::Migrator.new(:up, migrations_paths, nil)
  pending_migrations = migrator.pending_migrations
  unless pending_migrations.empty?
    puts "Migrating from #{migrator.current_version} to #{pending_migrations.last.version}"
    migrator.migrate

    require 'active_record/schema_dumper'
    filename = ENV['SCHEMA'] || "#{Rails.root}/db/schema.rb"
    File.open(filename, "w:utf-8") do |file|
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(Rails.env)
      ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.dump(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, file)
    end

  end

end
```

Update: Apparently the new version of Rake is more liberal about when it loads, so the expression `!defined?(Rake)` is always false, even when being run from the command line (i.e. not inside a Rake Task or a Resque Worker). I'm trying the following instead

```
caller.grep(/rake/).empty?
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my working version for Rails 3.2 on jRuby:

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate(Rails.root.join("db/migrate"), nil)
end
```

Comment: This seems to be working great for me.  I added this in my environments/development.rb file and added `unless $rails_rake_task` to the end to have it not run for rake tasks.

Comment: After `unless $rails_rake_task` I also added `|| ENV['SKIP_MIGRATIONS']` to allow easy skipping of migrations if a migration breaks and I need to get into the console: `SKIP_MIGRATIONS=true rails console`

Answer (score 2):

Put the following inside Rails::Initializer block in environment.rb ...

```
  config.after_initialize do
    ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate (RAILS_ROOT + "/db/migrate" )
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sam's Answer did not quite work for me. I'm using Rails 3.0, I think you might need to add this inside of application.rb, anywhere inside the class.

```
config.after_initialize do
  ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate (RAILS_ROOT + "/db/migrate" )
end
```

On a similar note, I'm using JRuby and Deploying as a War, I wonder why this is not creating the tables for me, instead it complains that table *such&such* does not exist.

Comment: To get it to create the tables in this environment, you must add `db/migrate` to your `config.dirs` in your `Warbler::Config.new do |config|` block...

Answer (score -3):

In my experience, db:migrate-like routine should only be called when new migrations are present, because it takes quite a bit of time. You shouldn't really have so many migrations that you can't track when they are present.

That said, the task of running new migration in production environment is best handled by deployment tools like Capistrano. when deploying to production box, capistrano runs migrations if you tell it too.

Running db:migrate-like routine upon every-init is resource and time wastful.

Comment: I benchmarked it and it takes < 0.2 seconds on my old machine.  Worth the time for me!  Most of the time of running rake db:migrate is loading rails which you're doing anyway when you load the server, so it'll actually save you time and the aggravation of forgetting to run migrations after pulling code.