# Google App Engine: Ruby on Rails - Execute migrations automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, migration

I was wondering if it was possible to run migrations automatically during deployment with Google App Engine. I have been using AWS Elasticbeanstalk for a while and they were ran automatically but now I am considering moving to the Google App Engine for my future projects.

Right now, I must run this command manually:

```
bundle exec rake appengine:exec -- bundle exec rake db:migrate GAE_CONFIG=app.yml
```

Thank you

Comment: Never tried to use App Engine, where do you run yr exec ?

Comment: appengine:exec is provided by the AppEngine gem which basically run the command in the Google App Engine instance. I run the command locally

Comment: I am not a user of appengine but quick lookup suggests you must have a app.yaml file, can you pleas share that as well.

Comment: How about we work around this, instead of defining task in appengine, what we can do is make migrations run automatically on app load in certain environments(or all if you want). You can take idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742665/rails-plugin-to-run-migrations-on-startup (its old, will need some updates obviously). Let me know if that works, if so i will add this as answer and you can accept that. :) I will be happy to help further if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**WARNING:** As discussed in comments, there is a race condition in migrations if deployment is done on multiple containers in parallel, because it will try to run migration on all containers. Solution is being discussed in comments, i will update this answer when we land on something.

**Disclaimer:** This answer is not exactly what was asked for, but it solves same problem and it works. And from what i can tell from question, doing it with some appengine config is not a requirement, rather he just want the migrations to run automatically.

I will expand on my comment on question, here is something i tried and it works. I am strong believer of **KISS(keep it simple and stupid)**. So instead of trying to figure out appengine(which i have never used anyway) if i were you, i would take a generic approach. Which is, to plug into rails server booting process and trigger migrations. For this we have multiple approaches.

With my understanding of appengine and suggested by [this official doc link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/ruby/using-ruby-libraries) **appengine has a `app.yaml` file, this file has an entry something like**:

```
entrypoint: rails server
```

So we will use this entry point to plug in our code to run migrations before starting server. For this i did this:

1. Make a new file in `bin` directory, i named it
   **`rails_with_migrations.sh`** you can name it whatever you like.
2. Give it execute permissions with **`chmod +x bin/rails_with_migrations.sh`**
3. Put this code inside it:

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec rake db:migrate
bundle exec rails $@
```

Of course you can give whatever RAILS_ENV you want to give these.

4. Now in **`app.yaml`** on the **`entrypoint`** section, instead of `rails server` give it `bin/rails_with_migrations.sh server` and it should be it. It worked on local, should work everywhere.

**NOTE:** In `entrypoint:` i have `bin/rails_with_migrations.sh server` here, server is rails command parameter, you can pass as much parameters as you like these all will be passed to `rails server` command with `$@`'s magic. It is there to allow you to pass port and any other parameters you may need to provide for your environment. Also it allows you to run `rails console` locally with `bin/rails_with_migrations.sh console` which will also cause migrations to get triggered.

**UPDATE1:** As per comment, i checked what happens if migration fails, and it starts server even if migration fail. We can alter this behavior of-course in our `sh` file.

**UPDATE2:** The shell-script with migration error code handling will look something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec rake db:migrate
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  bundle exec rails $@
else
  echo "Failure: migrations failed, please check application logs for more details." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

This update will prevent server from starting and causing a non zero exit code from the script, which should indicate that this command failed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I must admit it is a good suggestion. However, I am scared of one thing : Would the deploy actually "fail" if the migration fails.

Comment: Should it?
If so we can plug something in for that as well @Jamesst20

Comment: How can we alter this behavior in our sh file ? It's very important that the deployment fails, if the database migrations fail, it must not fail silently and I must be able to get the stacktrace from the deployment log.

Comment: @Jamesst20 `$?` variable gives us the status of last command run, if its 0 it menas it was ok. Otherwise it must have failed with some error. Now, i can modify script to not start server and exit with a non 0 exit code from the script, but about logging, i am not sure where appengine logs entrypoint failures. It should be either within the deploy command output, or you should be able to stream logs of the instance. I can modify the script, but you should figure out the log thing yourself. I will ask around too though.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I should be able to get things going with those informations :) !

Comment: Yeah sure, here to help in case of anything else you might need.

Comment: According to here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41450437/rails-migrations-dont-run-on-google-app-engine-deploy there could be a race condition proceeding this way :(

Comment: Seems reasonable potential issue if its true that appengine runs on multiple containers at the same time.

Comment: @Jamesst20 i think what we can do instead of this is now to first release and than run migrations. And put these two steps in a shell script and have it committed in the git repo. Something like, `deploy.sh` only issue here will be that it will report if migrations fail, but the system will still be up. You can instead write commands to 1- Take system down. 2- Deploy new code, 3- run migration, 4- up the system only if migrations succeeded. I will also add note to my answer that this is the problem here.

Comment: Sound about right. The only thing I can think of is 1. Deploy new code, 2. Enable maintenance mode, 3. Run migrations, 4. Disable maintenance mode if it went well. Deploying new code first is fine because if it fails, the traffics wont be redirected to that new instance. However, toggling the maintenance mode might not be that easy. I will check if it is possible to run from the bitbucket pipeline a rake task that toggles it.